# application crashed after dismiss presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, ios4, crash

i have a problem when going to another controller with the following buttons

```
-(IBAction)art:(id)sender{

TestYourInfoViewController *test = [[TestYourInfoViewController alloc]
                              initWithNibName:@"TestYourInfoViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
test.questionType = @"art";
testYourInfoViewC = test;
[testYourInfoViewC setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:testYourInfoViewC animated:YES ];
[test release];
```

}

and when i go back with the following

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender{
   [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

it crash the application with no stacktrace.. what is the wrong with that please.

Answer (score 0):

Is `testYourInfoViewC` defined in the header as a retained `@property`? If so, you should always be referring to it using `self` and dot notation.

```
- (IBAction)art:(id)sender
{
    TestYourInfoViewController *test = [[TestYourInfoViewController alloc]
                              initWithNibName:@"TestYourInfoViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    test.questionType = @"art";
    self.testYourInfoViewC = test;
    [self.testYourInfoViewC setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.testYourInfoViewC animated:YES ];
    [test release];
}
```

When you create a retained `@property` and `@synthesize` it, a setter is being created that handles the memory management involved in retaining the new object and releasing the old, but by assigning `test` to `testYourInfoViewC` you're bypassing that synthesized setter.

Let's step through this here. You've created `test` using `alloc/init`, thus setting its retainCount to 1. Next you've assigned `testYourInfoViewC` to `test`. No change in the retain count, `testYourInfoViewC` is now simply pointing to the same object as `test` instead of retaining a copy for itself.

Now when you call `release` on `test` that retain count returns to 0 and the object is deallocated. Your instance of `TestYourInfoViewController` is completely gone and `testYourInfoViewC` is now left flapping in the wind. When attempting to dismiss it, the `parentViewController` is going to attempt to send some messages to that object behind the scenes, like `-viewWillDisappear:`, `-viewDidDisappear:` etc.

**Edit:** Here's how I handle this kind of situation in my projects. I override the getter for the property and determine whether it needs to be created or not. This way I can call the property anywhere in my code and I can be assured that if its not created it will be allocated, initialized and setup just in time.

```
- (TestYourInfoViewController *)testYourInfoViewC
{
    if (!testYourInfoViewC)
    {
        testYourInfoViewC = [[TestYourInfoViewController alloc] init]; // This will work because the .xib and class name are identical. 
        [testYourInfoViewC setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    }

    return testYourInfoViewC;
}
```

After you've setup the getter to provide lazy instantiation, your `-art:` method will look like this...

```
- (IBAction)art:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.testYourInfoViewC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: now after i do that it works just fine when i go back but if i pressed the button again to get (art) page it crash at the @synthesize testYourInfoViewC  ... also with no stacktrace!! what is that

Comment: I've edited my answer to show a more efficient solution to this problem.

Comment: will there's another strange problem when i say     testYourInfoViewC.questionType = @"art"; it didn't add to it unless i go back and enter the controller again

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to add that line back in. If `questionType` is something that can vary, you should set that in the `-art:` method. If it never changes, then set that line in the overridden getter.

Comment: yeah i noticed that  of course :) and my question after i added it and it work in the second time i go to the controller and after i change anything in the controller and back and return again it seems like the controller didn't get released it's just as i left it

Comment: If you want to force it to reload every time, just set `self.testYourInfoViewQ = nil`, in `-art:`.